# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'variable' in R

Tags: r, tensorflow

I am making a neural network in R so I can predict future data.

Firstly, I made a function that makes the layers:

```
add_layer <- function(x, in_size, out_size, act_function){
  w = tf$V=variable(tf$random_normal(shape(in_size, out_size)))
  b = tf$variable(tf$random_normal(shape(1, out_size)))
  wxb = tf$matmul(x,w)+ b
  y = act_function(wxb)
  return(y)
}
```

Then, I create the layers. For now, I create 2 layers:

```
x = tf$placeholder(tf$float32, shape(NULL,31))
ty = tf$placeholder(tf$float32, shape(NULL, 2))

#First layer
l1 = add_layer(x, 31, 10, tf$nn$relu)

#Second layer, result is 0(false) or 1(true)
l = add_layer(l1, 10,2, tf$nn$sotfmax)
```

But then there is an error when I make layer l1 and layer l:

```
 AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'variable'
```

The problem is, when I remove in_size or out_size, it gives me the error that these are missing. Do I add these two then it gives me this error. After filling all the parameters(in_size, out_size, x and the activation function) it still gives me variable missing as seen above.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Edit: Changed capital letter v, but result is still the same

Comment: Capital V, sir.

Comment: @benitok good catch! Unfortunately after changing it I still get the same error. 

Edit: I see that something else is wrong, you are right. Thanks sir!